# Swift iOS memory usage increasing during runtime

Tags: ios, swift, instruments

When I launch the application it will check to see if a user is currently logged in. If they are not then will set the root view controller to the landing page where they can sign up or sign in. If they are signed in then it will set the root view controller to an instance of the tab bar controller which contains three view controllers.

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
    window?.rootViewController = TabBarController()
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
    print("\(user.email ?? "user") is already logged in")
} else {
    let landingPageVC = LandingPageViewController()
    window?.rootViewController = landingPageVC
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.windowScene = windowScene
}
```

for some reason when I launch the application (in this case I am signed in) the app displays a blank white screen and I can see in the debug navigator that the app seems to be stuck in a loop allocating memory. After a couple minutes the app crashes and in the console it prints

**Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue**

I have used Instruments to observe if there is a memory leak but it just displays green ticks and indicates that there are no memory leaks. I have cleaned my build folder and also deleted the build from my phone and the issue still persists.

[image]

Comment: It is looks like some infinity loop somewhere inside your project. If this occurs only when you are signed in, then I would search for this infinity loops inside the "signed in" part of project - from TabBarController trough each VC what your TabBar contains.

Comment: @Virender I am unable to see my view controller layout it just displays a blank white screen

Comment: @LukášMareda so it appears that it all works when I remove the first view controller from the tab bar which is the HomeViewController. The white screen is no longer being displayed and I can interact with the app and the memory usage is no longer increasing. What should I be looking for that is causing this infinity loop?

Comment: it is looks like it is something wrong in 'HomeViewController'. I can help you, only if I see what is inside.

Comment: Post your ```HomeViewController``` code here. The problem is somewhere there. Do you have any `for-loop` in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Profile Memory Allocation

I made a test iOS application to show how you could profile memory allocation. After creating a new iOS project I added the following to the `AppDelegate`:

```
var test: [String] = []

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    while true {
        test.append("blasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdfblasdgpjsogfisogfihsofighäkneäijifdf")
    }
    return true
}
```

This should simulate your problem. Then we longpress the build button and choose profile.

[image]

We choose Allocations as profiling template.

[image]

We press the record button.

[image]

We once again select Allocations.

[image]

We select Call Trees.

[image]

And probably we already find the problematic stack trace on the right side.

[image]

Or you scan the call tree by yourself.

[image]

This should give you a starting point for further debugging to find the infinite loop :)

Comment: I was able to find that the memory increasing directly correlated with a UITableViewCell being initialised without a reuse identifier. I still don't know why it was looping however through the detailed process you have provided I was able to find a solution to my specific problem.